# Why is a JPEG file size of a PDF bigger than original PDF?

Tags: pdf, jpeg, pdfbox

For the purpose of taking up less space, I'm taking all pages inside a single PDF and stacking them vertically in a single JPG image using PDFBox.

```
  BufferedImage combinedImage = new BufferedImage(maxWidth, maxHeight, TYPE_INT_RGB);
  int currentYPlacement = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < document.getPages().getCount(); i++) {
    BufferedImage currentImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(i, 72, ImageType.RGB);

    Graphics graphics = combinedImage.getGraphics();
    graphics.drawImage(currentImage, 0, currentYPlacement, null);
    currentYPlacement += currentImage.getHeight();
  }
  File outputfile = new File( "test.jpg");
  ImageIO.write(combinedImage, "jpg", outputfile);
```

However, I found that the JPG file size is not always smaller than the PDF size.  I still want the images to remain readable and be the original dimensions of the PDF.

I know that one thing to consider is that a PDF is very small (< 50 KB) and a JPG of that size could be bigger but I'm not sure what else is there to consider.

Here are my findings, notice the difference between the two 1-page PDFs. How is the second 1-page result almost 2x as big as the original PDF?  What factors are affecting the JPG size?

| # of pages | PDF size | JPG size | Result | Sample PDF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 178 KB | 88 KB | 50.5618% decrease | https://www.tn.gov/content/dam/tn/revenue/documents/forms/titlereg/f1310601Fill-in.pdf |
| 1 | 95 KB | 135 KB | 42.1053% increase | https://dmv.nv.gov/pdfforms/nvl010.pdf |
| 2 | 144 KB | 169 KB | 17.3611% increase | https://www.tn.gov/content/dam/tn/commerce/documents/regboards/mvc/forms/CONSIGNMENT_AGREEMENT.pdf |
| 2 | 372 KB | 184 KB | 50.5376% decrease | https://www.honolulu.gov/rep/site/csd/onlineforms/csddlapplicationform.pdf |

**Update**

I create a 8.5 x 11 PDF in Microsoft Word with the words "Hello, World!" and performed the conversion.  The PDF was **23 KB** and the JPG file is **14 KB** after the conversion.  Very confusing...

Comment: PDFs will often include a lot of non-raster content, for instance: text and vector art. These things can become very heavy once you rasterize them and have to store all of that info in pixel data.

Comment: Open notepad and type 1 screen of text.  Take a screen capture, save as JPEG.  Notice the bitmap takes up much more space than the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no relation between the PDF file size (in kB) and the converted page image size (in kB).

When you convert a PDF page to image, the size of the output image, in pixels, is computed as follows:

```
sizeOfImageInPixels = sizeOfPDFPageInPoints * dpi / 72;
```

If you have a PDF file with a single letter page (612 * 792 points), when you convert this page to image at 72 dpi, the output image will be 612 * 792 pixels. If the image is RGB only (24 bits per pixel), then its size will be

```
612 * 792 * 3 = 1454112 bytes.
```

So no matter the size of the PDF file is (it can be a light kB empty PDF page or a heavy MB full PDF page with full color images, text, vector graphics, etc), when it is converted to image at 72dpi, the size of the output uncompressed image will always be 1454112 bytes.

Now, when you compress these 1454112 bytes, the compressed output size will vary as a full white page (all bytes 255) will compress much better than a colored page. Since JPEG is a lossy compression, same uncompressed image can be JPEG compressed to different sizes depending on how aggressive the compression is.